# Image is not displaying center in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi in the below code Image is not displaying center and text want to display at the bottom of the screen.

but Image also displaying bottom and text also bottom ,Loading also should be both at a time.

Now text is displaying first after sometime image is displaying.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import 'login_screen.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                    name: "Genvcare",
                  )),
          (route) => false);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0769AA),
      body:Container(

        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [


              Column(

                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/bluelogo.png'),
                    ),

                    Text("From",textAlign: TextAlign.end),
                    Text("@2016 Google Health Pvt Ltd.",textAlign: TextAlign.end,),
                    Text("Version 1.3.4.7.0"),
                  ])
        ]
        )
      ),
       );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. and add `mainAxisAlignment` to the Column widget to `MainAxisAlignment.center`

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
          // add your image path instead of my image -> Image.asset('assets/images/bluelogo.png')
          child: Image.network(
              'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png'),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child:Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "From",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                ),
                Text(
                  "@2016 Google Health Pvt Ltd.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Version 1.3.4.7.0",
                ),
              ],
            ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Image is displaying center but text are displaying below the image not at the bottom end

Comment: @JyothiSri check my updated answer and try it just change my image with your image

Comment: @JyothiSri Most Welcome Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple using [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(//to occupy all the avaliable width
        child: Column(// to arange elements vertically
          children: [
            Expanded(// to take all the remaining avaliable space in Column
              child: Image.network( // you can replace this with image form assets
                'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1393171?s=200&v=4'
              ),
            ),
            const Text.rich( // You can replace this with Text('yourtext',align:TextAlign.center)
              TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(text: 'From\n'),
                TextSpan(text: '@2016 Google Health Pvt Ltd.\n'),
                TextSpan(text: 'Version 1.3.4.7.0\n')
              ]),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: SplashScreen screenshot]